# Change Amazon AMI Timezone

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

How do you change the timezone for the system clock for a EC2 instance running the Amazon AMI?

Comment: Which AMI would that be? Which Linux distro? Are you looking to change the tz for one deployed instance of that AMI or for the image itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using redhat based distro:

Go to `/usr/share/zoneinfo` and find your TimeZone which you would like to switch to.

Then copy that file to `/etc/localtime`

Your time zone will be updated.

More details can be found [here](http://www.geekride.com/howto-change-timezone-linux-unix/).